# Call function from parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

Page A has iframe B. In iframe B, I have a var store a function name of page A. How to call that function from iframe B? (Both in a same domain)

I try this in iframe B

```
eval("window.parent." + func_name + "('"+param1+"', '"+param2+"');");
```

It work well but I ask for a better solution if possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To avoid the eval you can write:

```
window.parent[func_name](param1,param2)
```

Comment: it may be obvious to most, but I just learned the hard way that func_name is a string, so if we want to pass the function name as a literal, we need to write `window.parent['myfunction'](param1, param2);`